# Abelian groups whose finite subgroups are cyclic

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

If $(F,+,\times)$ is any field, then the abelian group $(F-\{0\},\times)$ has property that every finite subgroup of it is cyclic.

**Question:** If $G$ is an abelian group such that every finite subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, then can $G$ be embedded in the multiplicative group of some field?

It should be noted that if $G$ is an abelian group such that every finite subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ may not be *isomorphic* to the multiplicative group of some field. For example, if $G$ is cyclic group of order $5$ then $G$ can not be isomorphic to $(F-\{0\},\times)$ for any field, because, then $|F|$ will be $6$, impossible.

The point to say here is that in question, I am stressing on *embedding of $G$* rather than *isomorphism of $G$ with $(F-\{0\},\times)$*.

Comment: I bet $\mathbb{C}^\times$ would do a job.

Comment: Perhaps, if $G$ is *finite* abelian with property in question, then you are right.

Comment: As a special case you could ask whether every torsion free abelian group embeds in the multiplicative group of a field.

Comment: I think you can. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930729/when-can-an-infinite-abelian-group-be-embedded-in-the-multiplicative-group-of-a), but I would have to think more to actually understand it (I am not familiar with some of the concepts). Pretty sure the torsion subgroup of such groups is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (the torsion subgroup is countable since if they were not there would be two cyclic subgroups $\langle a \rangle, \langle b \rangle$ of the same order but $\langle a,b \rangle$ would not be cyclic).

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question is Yes.

A universally axiomatizable class of structures is called a
**universal class.** Such classes have been characterized as classes
closed under the formation of substructures and ultraproducts.

Let $\mathcal A$ be the class of those abelian groups $A$ embeddable in
the multiplicative group of some field.
Let $\mathcal B$ be the class of those abelian groups $B$ whose finite
subgroups are cyclic. The following are true.

1. $\mathcal A$ is a universal class. [Reason: it is clear that
   $\mathcal A$ is closed under the formation of substructures.
   If $\{A_i\;|\;i\in I\}\subseteq \mathcal A$
   is a class of abelian groups, each
   embeddable in the multiplicative group of a field, then each
   ultraproduct that can be formed from this set
   is embeddable in the multiplicative group of
   the corresponding ultraproduct of 
   fields. This ultraproduct is itself a field.]
2. $\mathcal B$ is a universal class. [Reason: one can write
   down the universal sentences that axiomatize $\mathcal B$.
   Beyond the axioms that say, *I am an abelian group,* one should
   include, for each $n$, a first-order 
   axiom that says, *for all $x, y$, if $x$ and $y$ both have
   exponent $n$, then $x$ is a power of $y$ or $y$ is a power of $x$*.
   Here I am considering abelian groups as multiplicative groups.]
3. $\mathcal A\subseteq \mathcal B$. [Reason: it is well known that
   a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.]
4. $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal A$. [Reason: It is a general fact
   about universal classes that if $\mathcal B\not\subseteq \mathcal A$,
   then there is a finitely generated $B\in \mathcal B-\mathcal A$.
   A finitely generated member of
   $\mathcal B$ has the form $\mathbb Z^k\oplus \mathbb Z_m$.
   So to establish this claim
   it suffices to show that groups of this form are embeddable in
   multiplicative groups of fields. To embed this group, choose
   algebraically independent elements $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_k\in\mathbb C$
   and let $\zeta\in\mathbb C$ be a primitive $m$-th root of unity.
   The multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb C$ generated by
   $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k,\zeta\}$ is isomorphic to
   $\mathbb Z^k\oplus \mathbb Z_m$, so we are done.]