# Does there exist an infinite non-abelian group such that all of its proper subgroups become cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have simple examples of *finite* groups (that may be abelian or not) that are not cyclic but all their proper subgroups are cyclic (e.g. *Klein's $4$-group* and $S_3$ respectively for abelian and non-abelian). In recent times, I have been able to produce a few examples of *infinite* abelian groups that are not cyclic but all their proper subgroups are cyclic.

But currently, I am pondering whether the same can also be said for some *infinite non-abelian* group or not, precisely, does there exist an infinite non-abelian group such that all of its proper subgroups become cyclic?

And if there do exist such groups, what can be an example?

And ***if possible***, it will be very much helpful if someone can give a *general algorithm* for constructing such a group.

Comment: If $a,b$ are non-commuting members of such a group, the subgroup $<a,b>$ generated by the set $\{a,b\}$ is non-Abelian, hence non-cyclic, hence must be the whole group.

Comment: (continued from my prior comment) : This also applies to (e.g) $<a,ab>$ and to $<a,ba>$ and to $<a^2,b>$.... I dk the answer to whether such groups exist.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet please give a precise and rigorous argument about what you mean to say.

Comment: Tarski monsters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Comment: Can you give an example of an infinite abelian group where all proper subgroups are cyclic?

Comment: @Myridium Consider $G = \{z \in \Bbb C : \exists n \in \Bbb N $ so that $z^n =1 \}$ with the usual multiplication of complex numbers.

Comment: @Myridium I think you should ask your query as a separate question, not in a comment of some other question !

Answer (score 4):

**Response to the original question:**

Such non-abelian groups, that all their proper subgroups are cyclic (and moreover, such that all their proper subgroups are isomorphic to $C_p$ for a fixed prime $p$) actually do exist. Such groups are called Tarski Monster Groups and there are continuum many of them for each prime $p > 10^{75}$ (this fact was proved by Alexander Ol'shansky in 1979).

**Response to the comment by @Myridium:**

The infinite abelian groups, that all their proper subgroups are cyclic can be described in the following way:

> If all proper subgroups of an infinite abelian group $G$ are cyclic, then $G$ is isomorphic either to $C_\infty$ (infinite cyclic), or to $C_{p^\infty}$ (quasicyclic for some prime $p$), or to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_+$, which consists of fractions with powers of a prime $p$ in denominators).

To prove this statement we will need two lemmas:

**Lemma 1:**

> If all proper subgroups of an infinite abelian group $G$ are cyclic, then $G$ is locally cyclic

If $G$ is finitely genersted, then by classification of finitely generated abelian groups it is isomorphic to $C_\infty$.

If $G$ is infinitely generated then all its finitely generated subgroups are proper, and thus cyclic.

**Lemma 2:**

> A group is locally cyclic iff it is a subquotient of $\mathbb{Q}_+$

The complete proof of this fact can be found [there](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_iff_subquotient_of_rationals)

**Proof of the main statement:**

If $G$ is finitely generated, then it is $C_\infty$

If $G$ is infinitely generated periodic, then it has a quasicyclic subgroup (by classification of locally cyclic groups). And as quasicyclic groups are not cyclic, this subgroup is the whole group.

If $G$ is infinitely generated aperiodic, then its quotient by an infinite cyclic subgroup is infinitely generated periodic and also satisfies the required property. So $G$ is a locally cyclic extension of $C_\infty$ by $C_{p^\infty}$ for some prime $p$, which can be only $\mathbb{Q}_p$.