# Give an example of a noncyclic infinite Abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups, p-adic-number-theory, infinite-groups

We have already seen this question that ["Give an example of a noncyclic Abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are cyclic."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185508/give-an-example-of-a-noncyclic-abelian-group-all-of-whose-proper-subgroups-are-c/185581#185581). Now the easiest answer is $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ and the bit more interesting result(this is interesting in number-theoretic ways and Galois theoretic way as well) is $G=\{a/2^k| a\in \Bbb Z, k\in \Bbb N\}$

Here I have proved that this is a non-cyclic group but the thing I could not understand is why every proper subgroup is cyclic. Now please read this few liner [blog](https://danaernst.com/an-infinite-non-cyclic-group-whose-proper-subgroups-are-cyclic/). The argument that is given [here](https://danaernst.com/an-infinite-non-cyclic-group-whose-proper-subgroups-are-cyclic/). **"Suppose $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ then Since $H$ is a proper subgroup, there exists a smallest $m∈\Bbb N$ such that no element of H has a denominator equal to $2^m$."** You can read that because the article was written just after the [first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185508/give-an-example-of-a-noncyclic-abelian-group-all-of-whose-proper-subgroups-are-c/185581#185581) raised in math stack. I could not understand that immediately why there should always exist one such big $m$ because $H$ is proper. I was thinking that what will happen if $(5/2)^n \in H$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, then we have to calculate a bit to prove(might be!!) that $H=G$ or what will happen if we have some other similar cases. Is the reason obvious? Is there any other way that I am missing.

By the way, another interpretation of $\Bbb Z(p^{\infty})$ is not G in the [first math stack post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185508/give-an-example-of-a-noncyclic-abelian-group-all-of-whose-proper-subgroups-are-c/185581#185581)

Comment: Isn't $H = \{3a/2^k : a \in {\mathbb Z}, k \in {\mathbb N} \}$ a non-cyclic proper subgroup of $G$ of index $3$?

Comment: To some extent this is my question. I don't know about the authenticity of the blog. $H$ is proper(obvious) it is non cyclic because if some $H=<3a/2^k>$ where a is odd then they can't generate $3/2^{k+1}$ and so on.

Comment: It seems this blog post is just false. Clearly the subgroup given by @DerekHolt is a counterexample to the claim about the smallest $m$, since all $3/2^m$ are in $H$.